# hg mercurial multiple interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, interface, mercurial

Can hg mercurial server be cloned by multiple interfaces?

Be cloned, for example, by users from different subnetworks on eth0 (194.169.1.x) and also the other subnetwork from eth1 (193.168.1.x).

I tried setting the hgrc file (address = eth1_IP), but it did not work.

By the way, my server is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: According to the [`hgrc` docs](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html), `address` is the setting for the *server* to bind to. You want two different client ip addresses to be able to clone it? It should be able to already assuming the clients can reach the server over the network. Maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Reading the [hgrc docs](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) @ubomb listed, the default device is "all". What happens if you removed the `address` setting?

Comment: The server will bind to all available addresses. Generally, it will bind to its LAN address (typically 192.168.1.xxx) and its public address (whatever is assigned by your ISP).

Answer (score 0):

By default (without defining `address` in [`\[web\]` section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web) in .hgrc) or using `-a ADDRESS` option in `hg serve` command, hg serve listed on all detected local interfaces

```
>hg serve
listening at http://tower:8000/ (bound to *:8000)

>netstat -nao

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
...
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2496
...
```

(I'm too lazy show successful clone from my both interfaces)